# Files visibility across different profiles

Tags: profile, administration, sharing, files

I am having two different profiles like manager and technician. If a file uploaded by a manager for an order then it must not be visible to technician but the file uploaded by the technician for the same order must be visible to both technician and manager.

I am not using apex to save the uploaded files. Its just file upload component using screen flow.

If it is record then we can achieve through OWD but since files I am not able to

Comment: did you look at putting the file into different libraries where you can then grant membership to?

Comment: Actually its a file upload component. So attachments are saving against the record and cant move to different library

Comment: well, you could use a Flow or trigger to move out of `Attachment` into `ContentVersion` and then create a `ContentDocumentLink` and a `ContentWorkspaceDocument`

Comment: Actually files are already stored in ContentDocumentLink only. So do I have to try with moving from ContentDocumentLink  to ContentWorkspaceDocument . If like that means whether the file will be show in related list of that record?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Play with the share values on ContentDocumentLink after associating to a library.  Others may have a better answer